# Setting Xbox Dashboard Images in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, xbox360

I am wondering if there is a way in XNA to set the Xbox dashboard images (see image). I know that this can be done through the App hub when it is published, however, we would like to have this done before publication.

Thank you in advanced for your response.

[image: XNA Game missing cover image on Xbox.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be much information available on this issue.

From my own knowledge of how it works, those images are downloaded from the Xbox LIVE service rather than bundled with your game, and there is no API available in the XNA Framework that allows you to bundle and display that image.

Comment: My research showed the same. I was just hoping that this wasn't the case. Anyway, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

You can not set the image in your project until it is reviewed by others and published onto the xbox live.
http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/109442/647571.aspx